# Create Office 365 Groups programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, office365

Microsoft recently released the Office 365 Groups feature:
(http://www.sharepointtalk.net/2015/01/the-anatomy-of-office-365-groups.html?showComment=1429612834863#c6525209790902174448)

I would like to create Office 365 Groups programmatically, but i am not sure how to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For Office 365 Groups see this office graph API sample from [Microsoft Office 365 Graph API](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_groups)

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 244

{
  "description": "description-value",
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "securityEnabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported, however this would be a very nice feature to have with the new Office 365 APIs recently released if we can get it. 
Reference:
http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/345331.aspx

Comment: At BUILD2015 there was a session on groups and the new o365 unified api.  Shows what you can and can't do.  Below is the link.  Enjoy...

Deep Dive into the Office 365 Groups REST API - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-701/ - Yina Arenas / Rohit Nagarmal

Answer (score 1):

More on groups - create.  You cannot create distribution groups programmatically, but you can create security groups.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/office-365-unified-api-reference#msg_ref_entitySet_groups
groups
Summary : Representing a tenant-level resource collection of the unified Group type. Use a POST request against this collection to create a group and add it to the collection. Use a GET request to view existing groups collection.
Path :/{tenant}/groups
Operations :POST, GET

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974486.aspx
You can only create security groups using Azure AD Graph (you cannot create mail-enabled security groups or mail distribution groups). For this reason the mailEnabled property must be set false and the securityEnabled property must be set true when creating a group.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Office 365 unified API you can create groups.
There are 4 types of groups: DLs, Security Groups, Email enabled Security Groups and Unified Groups.
Unified groups are the ones that have content, like conversations, events and files.

You can create groups by doing a POST to https://graph.microsoft.com and passing the groupType='Unified'

However, due to the distributed nature of the services, after creating the unified group via the API, you will not get instant access to the group content.

In addition, the groups functionality is still being deployed to all the production services so you might not have it in your tenant yet.